# Identifying & Printing an object within an object - Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, object

I have a JSON in the following format:

```
{
    key: value,
    key: value,
    key: {
       key: value,
       key: value
    }
}
```

I want to print these key values out to my page using Angular's ngIf to identify if the value is a string or another object. I tried using `typeof` but it gives me an unresolved variable error in Webstorm.

How do I know that the value is an object and that I need to go in and take key values from in there?

I am using Angular 6 & Webstorm IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to get that value.[Take a look at this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfj84w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In `component.ts`:

```
checkType(data){
  return typeof(data)
}
```

In `html`:

```
<div *ngIf="checkType(data.k1) === 'string'">
  I am string
</div>
```